# What is the purpose of views' predefinitions in dump file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg-dump

I'm working on the project where we are using [`:sql` schema format](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps) for the Active Record dumper (to support more complex logic like triggers).

We have a lot of views and I can see in the `database/structure.sql` file that some of them have "predefined" schema with `NULL`s like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW public.my_view AS
  SELECT
    NULL::integer AS record_id,
    NULL::integer AS another_record_id,
    NULL::double precision AS some_field;
```

Then, thousands of lines later, the definition is added with:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_view AS
  -- actual query
```

I can't see any references to the view between schema "predefinition" and definition with my SQL query. Also, there are other views that are created right away (without that schema "predefinition").

I was looking in Active Record documentation but I couldn't find any hints. Rails uses `pg_dump` under the hood but I don't see anything relevant in `pg_dump` docs too.

Why some views require predefining the schema in advance, while others don't, even if none of them are referenced between predefinition and actual definition in `database/structure.sql` file? Is it to prevent some race conditions when using yet another structure (like materialized views or something)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because views can have circular dependencies like this:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA s;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s.v AS SELECT 1 a;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s.w AS SELECT a FROM s.v;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s.v AS SELECT a FROM s.w;
```

Those views can't be queried in this form. E.g. `select * from s.w` produces:

> SQL Error [42P17]: ERROR: infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "w"

But running the following `pg_dump` command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d postgres -s -n s
```

Produces this output:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA s;

CREATE VIEW s.v AS
SELECT
    NULL::integer AS a;

CREATE VIEW s.w AS
 SELECT v.a
   FROM s.v;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s.v AS
 SELECT w.a
   FROM s.w;
```

As you can see, there's your dummy view which has to be created, because `s.v` couldn't access the not-yet existing `s.w` at the point of creation.

You can also find this logic in [`pg_dump.c`'s `createDummyViewAsClause` function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2cb1272445d2a6616991fc6ede274d9f1f62ff73/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L14988), whose documentation reads:

```c
/*
 * Create a dummy AS clause for a view.  This is used when the real view
 * definition has to be postponed because of circular dependencies.
 * We must duplicate the view's external properties -- column names and types
 * (including collation) -- so that it works for subsequent references. [...]
 */
```

Comment: Nice, it is kind of  **forward declaration** in SQL world. Sometimes such approach is required for [repeateable scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004054/5070879) to produce stub of the db object.