# Repeatable Migration in Order

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-migration, flyway

Requirement: Need Flyway to execute R scripts in sequence

Issue: As we are migrating all the functions and procedures to new DB, Some of the function internally calls another function as the example below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ABC() RETURNS TABLE (
       COLUMNS
    ) LANGUAGE SQL AS '
      SELECT ID from TABLE(ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ID()) AS c
```

So here both the functions `FN_ABC` and `FN_ID` are new functions that need to be created in the new DB

So issue is when executed via Flyway it creates `FN_ABC` as First and it fails as the `FN_ID` doesn't exists

How I can resolve this issue so I can get the function `FN_ID` created first and then `FN_ABC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to put all definitions in single file at the begining defined as "stub" function.

Related: **[Forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)** - parameters list and output must match actual ones:

Here:

```
-- forward declaration, only signatures
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ABC() RETURNS TABLE (
       ID INT
    ) LANGUAGE SQL AS '
      SELECT NULL';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ID() RETURNS TABLE (
       ID INT
    ) LANGUAGE SQL AS '
      SELECT NULL';

-- here actual definition in any order
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ABC() RETURNS TABLE (
       COLUMNS
    ) LANGUAGE SQL AS '
      SELECT ID from TABLE(ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ID()) AS c
```

Comment: Can I have forward definition ONLY for `ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ID()` before the actual definition of `ABC_SCHEMA.FN_ABC()` ??  Or I should define both function as forward function?

Comment: @Karthik I would define signatures for all functions as in the future you may have ABC_SCHAME.FN_XYZ(dependend on FN_ABC) Having all signatures defined at the begining  should be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: I am maintaining each function in each separate file  as R__** scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can execute repeatable migrations in order, it's just a matter how your file is named:

- R__01_my_first_repeatable_script.sql
- R__02_my_second_repeatable_script.sql
- R__03_my_third_repeatable_script.sql

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found, is to put all dependent migrations in a single file, which then gets executed in order.

It's obviously not ideal as that file can get pretty big and complicated, so I hope someone will answer with a better solution.